# Regex to split email address in python

Tags: python

I have this

```
email = 'james@rmit.edu.au'
```

output

```
james rmit edu.au
```

but need to get this

```
james

rmit

au
```

---

```
email ='james@rmit.edu.au'
first_part, second_pst= email.rsplit('@',1)
domain_name, tld = second_part.split('.',1)`
```

Comment: It would really help if you wrote down your requirements instead of just giving an example. Are the double line breaks in your example significant or just an artefact of SO formatting? Did you omit the `edu` part of the address on purpose? What are the rules for other 3-level domain names? Unambiguous requirements are a key factor in getting code right :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
email = 'james@rmit.edu.au'

f1, f2 = email.rsplit('@',1)

domain_name, tld = [f2.rsplit('.')[i] for i in (0,-1)]

print(f1)
print(domain_name)
print(tld)
```

Output:

```
james
rmit
au
```

Answer (score 1):

A oneliner:

```
import re
email ='james@rmit.edu.au'
name, domain ,_ , tld = re.split('[@.]',email)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
result = re.split("@|\.edu\.", email)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Split](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split) return a list.

```
email ='james@rmit.edu.au'
first_part, second_part= email.rsplit('@',1)
sec = second_part.split('.')
print(first_part) #james
print(sec[0]) #rmit
print(sec[1]) #edu
print(sec[2]) #au
print(sec[-1] #also print au
```

Considering you will always want the name, company and country:

```
email ='james@rmit.edu.au'
first_part, second_part= email.rsplit('@',1)
sec = second_part.split('.')
print(first_part) #james
print(sec[0]) #company always be the first    
print(sec[-1] #country always be last one
```

Answer (score 0):

using regex:

```
import re

rex = re.compile(r"^([^@]+)@([^.]+).*\.([a-z]+)$", re.IGNORECASE)
a, b, c = rex.findall(email)[0]

print(a, b, c) # prints: james rmit au
```

in plain python:

```
email = "james@rmit.edu.au"
user, domain = email.split("@")
first_token, _, last_token = domain.split(".")

print(user, first_token, last_token) # prints: james rmit au
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
email = 'james@rmit.edu.au'
a, b, c = re.findall('^\w+|(?<=@)\w+|\w+$', email)
```

Output:

```
['james', 'rmit', 'au']
```