# Split Email Address (attention to second level domain!)

Tags: python, pandas, email

I'm trying to correctly split Email addresses like so:

| Email | Provider | Domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name.surname@something.com | something | com |
| name.surname@something.city.com | something | city.com |

In other words I would like to create 2 columns, df['Provider'] and df['Domain'], starting from df['Email'].

My first failed try was using:

```
df['Provider'] = (df['Email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.split('.').str[0]

df['Domain'] = (df['Email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.split('.').str[1]
```

but it fails to recognize the domain of the Email, and the result is something like that:

| Email | Provider | Domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name.surname@something.com | something | com |
| name.surname@something.city.com | something | city |

I have found a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57558385/regex-to-split-email-address-in-python) that solves this problem, but I'm struggling to understand how to correctly use it for my df

```
email = 'name.surname@something.city.com'

f1, f2 = email.rsplit('@',1)

provider_email, domain_email = [f2.rsplit('.')[i] for i in (0,-1)]
```

I don't have to necessarily use this function, but this is the best I could find to solve my problem, do you have any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add number of splits:

```
df['Provider'] = (df['Email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.split('.', 1).str[0]

df['Domain'] = (df['Email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.split('.', 1).str[1]
```

Also try:

```
(df['Email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.split('.', 1, expand=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the devil is in the details, this fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Provider'] = (df['Email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.split('.').str[0]

df['Domain'] = (df['Email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.split('.').str[-1]
```

output:

```
                             Email   Provider Domain
0       name.surname@something.com  something    com
1  name.surname@something.city.com  something    com
```

Rather than taking first occurence after . split take last occurence then it will fetch correct data for you